# Visual Studio will not recognize new Settings File

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, settings

I am attempting to use a new settings file in my Windows Forms Application with C#.

After I deleted the old Settings File (Settings1.settings) and created the new one(Settings.settings).

As I began editing the code that uses the settings file I realized that the new settings file is not being recognized. Example:

[image]

There is a custom Settings Class being used from a namespace created by our company that is causing some of the conflict. How do I point the code at the right settings file?

Comment: Do *not* mess with the .settings file yourself, only the IDE should do that.  Try to recover by deleting it in the Solution window, Project + Properties, Settings and click the link to create a new one.

Comment: thats what I did with the one I currently have in my Properties Folder. The previous one was all code and had no corresponding Graphical table information

Comment: Good Lord man, you are utterly lost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In trying to duplicate what you have done I noticed the Namespace of the Settings.Designer.cs file went from this( I am using a console app to test).

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1.Properties {


    [global::System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute()]
    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editors.SettingsDesigner.SettingsSingleFileGenerator", "10.0.0.0")]
    internal sealed partial class Settings : global::System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase {

        private static Settings defaultInstance = ((Settings)(global::System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.Synchronized(new Settings())));

        public static Settings Default {
            get {
                return defaultInstance;
            }
        }

        [global::System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute()]
        [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
        [global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("False")]
        public bool Test {
            get {
                return ((bool)(this["Test"]));
            }
            set {
                this["Test"] = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

to

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1 {


    [global::System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute()]
    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editors.SettingsDesigner.SettingsSingleFileGenerator", "10.0.0.0")]
    internal sealed partial class Settings : global::System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase {

        private static Settings defaultInstance = ((Settings)(global::System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.Synchronized(new Settings())));

        public static Settings Default {
            get {
                return defaultInstance;
            }
        }

        [global::System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute()]
        [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
        [global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("False")]
        public bool Temp {
            get {
                return ((bool)(this["Temp"]));
            }
            set {
                this["Temp"] = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you will notice the Namespace went from ConsoleApplication1.Properties to ConsoleApplication1 so if you add .Properties to the Namespace of the new Settings file it should take care of your problem.

Comment: Had a similar issue where saving an existing settings file for the first time in VS 2015 (after migrating from VS 2010) resulted in a similar namespace shift. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check the namespace of the Settings file and then you have 2 options:

1. Add using to this namespace at the beginning of your .cs file.
2. Write the whole namespace of the Settings file before each time you try to use it.

Comment: where would I find that namespace

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party I know. Anyway, the solution for me was to delete the settings stored below

`C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\[your program name]\`